# OpenLayers: What is selectedFeatures.on('add', function(event) {

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geojson, jquery-events

What is the event `add` in `selectedFeatures.on('add', function(event) {`?

I'm trying to add a popup to an OpenLayers map. From OpenLayers Beginner's Guide, Gratier et. al., I grabbed the code to add information on the point to a fixed element on the page as sort of a proof of concept. I ultimately want a popup at the clicked point. But first I'm trying to understand this code. I can't find anything out about the `add` event. The `add` responds to a click. If `add` is changed to `click`, the clicked diamond changes to a default blue dot, but the `#address-info` is not changed.

Overview: a map is created and all points from a geojson are shown as small diamonds on the map in the `locationsLayer`. I want to click or hover (preferred) and have the `addressInfo` popup next to the diamond. The project has multiple layers of basemaps (removed from the code here). It's all in a Rails project. OL v6.5.0. jQuery v3.4.1.

```
console.log('olAllLocationsSimplified.js is the JavaScript being used.');
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import View from 'ol/View';
import GeoJSON from 'ol/format/GeoJSON';
import VectorLayer from 'ol/layer/Vector';
import VectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector';
import {Icon, Fill, Stroke, Style, Text, Circle} from 'ol/style';
import {transform} from 'ol/proj';
import LayerGroup from 'ol/layer/Group';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import Overlay from 'ol/Overlay';
import Point from 'ol/geom/Point';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';
import {transformExtent, fromLonLat} from 'ol/proj';
import Select from 'ol/interaction/Select';
import Feature from 'ol/Feature';

var baseLayers = new LayerGroup({
  title: 'Base maps—Historic and Current',
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM(),
    }),
  ],
});
var svgDiamond = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-diamond-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M6.95.435c.58-.58 1.52-.58 2.1 0l6.515 6.516c.58.58.58 1.519 0 2.098L9.05 15.565c-.58.58-1.519.58-2.098 0L.435 9.05a1.482 1.482 0 0 1 0-2.098L6.95.435z"/></svg>';
var styleDiamond = new Style({
  image: new Icon({
    opacity: 1,
    src: 'data:image/svg+xml;utf8,' + svgDiamond,
    scale: 0.5,
  }),
});

var vectorLocations = new VectorSource({
  url: 'map/locationmap',
  format: new GeoJSON(),
  projection: 'EPSG:3857',
})
// All the locations put on the map with a small diamond
var locationsLayer = new VectorLayer({
  source: vectorLocations, //  the geojson
  style: styleDiamond
});

var container = document.getElementById('popup');

// Create an overlay to anchor the popup to the map. 
// var overlay = new Overlay({
//   element: container,
//   autoPan: true,
//   autoPanAnimation: {
//     duration: 250,
//   },
// });

var map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [baseLayers, locationsLayer],
  // overlays: [overlay], // for popup
  view: new View({
    center: fromLonLat([-118.243507, 34.052211]),
    zoom: 15,
    maxZoom: 21,
  }),
});

var select = new Select({
  layers: [locationsLayer]
});
map.addInteraction(select);

var selectedFeatures = select.getFeatures();
selectedFeatures.on('add', function(event) {
  var feature = event.target.item(0);
  var addressInfo = feature.get('popup');
  $('#address-info').html('Clicked on: ' + addressInfo + '. Indicated with a blue dot.'); // This is working
});
selectedFeatures.on('remove', function(event) {
  $('#address-info').empty();
});
```

Comment: I don't see `.map('add'` in the posted code.  I see: `selectedFeatures.on('add', function(event) {` which listens for the `add` event on the `selectedFeatures` collection.

Comment: I'll change that. Not sure why I wrote that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: If `select.getFeatures()` https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_interaction_Select-Select.html#getFeatures return a Collection it is the `add` event of the collection https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Collection.CollectionEvent.html

Comment: @Mike That makes some sense to me. I should have dug deeper, but my knowledge is too shallow to see what's going on. What is being added to the collection? Isn't `selectedFeatures` all the geojson features?

Comment: It contains features which have been selected by the interaction (which wall be a subset of the features in the layers).  Features are added or removed from the collection as they are selected or deselected by user interaction.

Comment: @Mike Thank you. I'll work through that. I need to understand this better as I try to make a real popup. I don't see how to credit you comment as an answer.

Comment: select is an interaction (something interacting with the map) to select features. Add event is triggered when a feature has been added to the select feature collection (by clicking on it).

Comment: Thanks everyone. And as usual posting made my search somehow better. I just found several, new to me, links for OL popups. And I've been looking for a week or so.